# How can I set the width of HTML <select> element, without considering the width of each option

Tags: html, html-select, dropdown

Actually I know the select box `width` is set by the longest option in the list, but I want to increase the length (width) of a `select` html element.

I also searched and I understand this code `style="max-width:70%"` may work but it doesn't work for me.

The code below is mine:

```
<select class="form-control"style="max-width:70%">
    <option value="1">option 1 </option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should use `width` attribute instead of `max-width`.
correct your code to below sample:

```
<select class="form-control"style="width:150px">
    <option value="1">option 1 </option>
    <option value="2">option 2sdsdsdsd</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use css property `min-width` for increasing width of dropdown irrespective of the width of options.

html:

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="1">option 1 </option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

css:

```
.dropdown{
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This is, imo, a better solution; the others will trigger `overflow-y` behaviour.

Comment: Separation of concerns—keeping styling information in a stylesheet—is also far better than an inline style attribute.

Answer (score -3):

This will help you.

```
    <select class="form control"style="width:70%">
    <option value="1">option 1 </option>
    <option value="2">option 2sdsdsdsd</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: As a new user thanks for your contribution. Note however that your answer is a duplicate of Sheida's, which I'm sure you did not see when posting your answer. Furthermore you answer lacks in details. Other people have to parse the HTML in your code block and compare it with the one in the question to understand what do you mean. It would be much more helpful to provide a textual description of the solution and not just the code. Even better with a couple links to the relevant documentation. If you keep this in mind you'll provide more valuable answers.